# Node js mongodb module embedded document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using node module "mongodb" and just started with the schema architecture for it. I read the documentation of mongodb module and found that there is no way I can store reference to another document inside a document. I want to achieve something like below:

```
DocumentA
{
_id: ObjectID(123456789),
fieldA1: "test",
fieldA2: "test",
DocumentB: <ObjectId>
}

DocumentB
{
_id: ObjectID(09876543),
fieldB1: "test2",
fieldB2: "test2"
}
```

I want to query DocumentA by ObjectID(123456789) and fetch DocumentB also so that I can access the value if "fieldB2" & "fieldB1".
Is this possible to do in node js mongodb? If yes then please give me some knowledge or give me another solution(like, is querying twice for fetching inner object ok?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo does support the concept of [references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/), but they are very weak references. There is no constraints on what your reference may be, so it may be totally invalid.

I think that there are 2 concepts that you're missing:

1. Mongo does not have the concept of 'joins'. Its just not in their paradigm.
2. Instead Mongo favors embedding documents. So in your case, instead of having 2 documents, you can just have

.

```
DocumentA
{
_id: ObjectID(123456789),
fieldA1: "test",
fieldA2: "test",
DocumentB: {
    fieldB1: "test2",
    fieldB2: "test2"
    }
}
```

You can then just query for Document A and do whatever combinatoric logic you want with Document B because its right there with Document A

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That answer helped me and makes sense to me.